# How do i stop access to my index.html file using node and ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How do i stop access to index .html file and let people sign up on home.ejs, i was building a static website but now making a web app and want people to sign up.

i commented out the index section but still the index gets on first instead of home.

I want people to sign up first and then use the app

This is my code.

```
 //jshint esversion: 6
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

/* app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
}); */

app.get("/home", function(req, res){
    res.render("home")
})

app.listen(3000);

console.log('now the server is running')
```

Comment: Your using [static assets](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) from `public` which includes your `index.html` file. You probably don't want `index.html` as a static resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App using static assets from `public` which includes your `index.html` file.

You can remove index.html from a static source

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html"));
});
```

Or you can give a base path to static folder.

```
app.use('/public' ,express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: ohhh okay bro, thank you so much for the help :-)